# How can I change the source of a video after clicking a specific h3 tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, video-streaming

[image]So I'm currently trying to make a video streaming site but I'm a bit stuck.

I'm trying to make the episode selector change the source of the video but I am a little confused as to how I can make it change the source of the player. I'm also trying to make the text below the player change depending on which video is selected.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main-video">
            <div class="video">
                <video src="video link here"></video>
                <h3 class="ep-title">00. Prologue</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="episode-list">
            <div class="episode active">
                
                <img src="image link here" alt="">
                <h3 class="title">00. Prologue</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="episode">
                <img src="image link here" alt="">
                <h3 class="title">01. A Winter Day, A Fateful Night</h3>
            </div>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    let listVideo = document.querySelectorAll('.episode-list .episode');
    let mainVideo = document.querySelector('.main-video video');
    let title = document.querySelector('.main-video .title')

    listVideo.forEach(video =>{
        video.onclick = () =>{
            listVideo.forEach(episode => episode.classList.remove('active'));
            video.classList.add('active');
            };
        
    });
</script>
```

This is what my code for the page (excluding the nav bar and plyr code) currently looks like. I do apologise beforehand as my question might be a bit complicated (I lack braincells lol) but any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Added an image of the site for visualisation purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `mainVideo.setAttribute('src', YOURSOURCELINK);` should change the video src. To change the text of the title you can use `title.innerHTML = "NEWTEXT"`

An example for this could be:

the "index" argument is the index in the list (keep in mind js starts with 0 for the first index), so to get episode one you would use changeVideo(0), for episode two changeVideo(1) etc

```
var list = [{
    title: "Episode 1",
    src: "some source link"
},{
    title: "Episode 2",
    src: "seconde source link"
}];


function changeVideo(index){
    let mainVideo = document.querySelector('.main-video video');
    let title = document.querySelector('.main-video .title')

    mainVideo.setAttribute("src", list[index].src)
    title.innerHTML = list[index].title

}
```

then you would need a onclick event in your video select, for example add `onclick="changeVideo(1)"` in your `<div class="episode">`

Comment: hmm I see. Could I possibly store the source link and new text within a variable under the episode div? If so any clue as to how I could do that? (I'm quite new to javascript welp)

Comment: You could add a list or map with the links/titles mapped to the episode number and then instead of "NEWTEXT" or the sourcelink just add the variables you need

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how to implement this, could you possibly provide an example? (Thanks in advance btw)

Comment: I edited my post to hopefully give you an better example on how you could implement this

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know how it goes! :)

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong. So I added the variable and function within a script tag, but then when I write `<div class="episode" onclick="changeVideo(1)">` it seems to do nothing.  (I apologise for my absolute lack of braincells XD)

Comment: Dont worry, are your title and mainVideo lets selecting the right elements? (title selects .title, but your title has the class .ep-title). Did you click on the div? Try settings the onclick event directly in the text (the h3) and not the div

Comment: Seems to work from within the h3 tag, but how could I get it to work in the div? Currently I have 2 divs; an active and a normal one. Active one is used to highlight which div is currently selected by the user.

Comment: I fixed it! Added another dev called epdiv and it seems to work flawlessly now. Thank you so much <3

Comment: No Problem, Im glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('change-url');
const video = document.getElementById('video');


btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
   console.log(video)
   video.setAttribute('src','http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/Sintel.mp4');
})
```

```html
<button id="change-url">change url</button>
<br/><br/>

<video id="video" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" width="300px" controls autoplay></video>
```

Comment: This is slightly different but I do understand how it works. What I'm trying to do is change the url depending on what episode is selected. Any clue?